# how can I use a https proxy with Amazon go library?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, https, proxy

I'm trying to use Hashicorp Packer to create and upload an AWS VM.  I'm behind a http and https proxy, so when I set http_proxy and https_proxy (and HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY) I can use the aws cli to see my S3 containers with no problems; however Hashicorp Packer uses the AWS go libraries, and according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#configuring-a-proxy and https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport they +only+ support HTTP_PROXY and not HTTPS_PROXY.

Is there any way I can use the AWS Go library (or packages built using it, like Packer) with a HTTPS proxy?

Comment: I would expect HTTP_PROXY to be used for HTTPS too since this what [net.http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) seems to do when no HTTPS_PROXY is set. Have you tried?

Comment: you can check out this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845690/how-to-program-go-to-use-a-proxy/53202838#53202838

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine with HTTPS_PROXY. The default transport (see https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go#L40) uses a `ProxyFromEnvironment` function (see https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go#L259) which you can see supports both `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`