# How to program Go to use a proxy when using a custom transport?

Tags: go, proxy, http-proxy

How to write Go programs that use a proxy automatically according to the [proxy environment variables](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-set-the-proxy-setting-using-Linux-command-line-on-Ubuntu-14-04#)?

The `go get` itself [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383299/how-do-i-configure-go-to-use-a-proxy) the standard [proxy environment variables](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-set-the-proxy-setting-using-Linux-command-line-on-Ubuntu-14-04#), but i'm talking about the Go program/code itself.

This blog says,

> By default http.Client checks the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables before processes any http.Request.

I tried it, but it doesn't work for my following code:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
resp, err := client.Get(url)
```

Comment: How are you creating your custom transport? Note the quoted doc says "by default", but you're overriding the defaults.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyFromEnvironment

Comment: @Peter, _"ProxyFromEnvironment returns the URL of the proxy"_, that should be the same as what I specified in the terminal. I.e., the problem still holds, "_The go get itself support the standard proxy environment variables, but i'm talking about the Go program/code itself._"

Comment: @xpt, but you are not using it when creating the Transport. You have to assign it to the Proxy field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **http.ProxyFromEnvironment** method

```
  var PTransport = & http.Transport { Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment }
  client: = http.Client { Transport: PTransport }
```

ProxyFromEnvironment returns the URL of the proxy to use for a given request, as indicated by the environment variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY (or the lowercase versions thereof). HTTPS_PROXY takes precedence over HTTP_PROXY for https requests.

I have tried below code, it works, Just add in ur proxy details in terminal.

```
export http_proxy='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
export https_proxy='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
export HTTP_PROXY='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
export HTTPS_PROXY='http://user:password@prox-server:3128'
```

```js
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

  var PTransport = & http.Transport {
    Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment
  }
  client: = http.Client {
    Transport: PTransport
  }
  req, err: = http.NewRequest("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", nil)
  req.Header.Add("If-None-Match", `some value`)
  resp, err: = client.Do(req)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()

  bodyBytes, err: = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  bodyString: = string(bodyBytes)
  fmt.Printf("GET Response = %s \n", string(bodyString))


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chinmay! I wish I could give you more point than the +25.

Comment: `Run code snippet` does not work for this -- it is setup for JavaScript, not Go.

Answer (score 5):

Set the [Transport Proxy](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport.Proxy) field to [http.ProxyFromEnvironment](https://godoc.org/net/http#ProxyFromEnvironment) to use a proxy configured from environment variables:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
  Proxy: ProxyFromEnvironment,
  TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
```

It's usually best to clone the [default transport](https://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultTransport) and set your options in that transport:

```
tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
tr.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
resp, err := client.Get(url)
```

The default transport includes the correct value for the Proxy field, timeouts and other useful settings.

If the application is not creating a custom transport, then none of this is required to honor the proxy related environment variables.

Comment: Note that `DefaultTransport` already includes `Proxy: ProxyFromEnvironment`, so the initial statement is kind of misleading -- if you aren't constructing a non-default transport, *you* may not need to set the proxy at all (as demonstrated in the second example).  An even simpler example that will use a proxy: `client := &http.Client{}`

Comment: I upvoted this approach because the second example looked smart.  Unfortunately, it doesn't compile: `invalid indirect of http.DefaultTransport (type http.RoundTripper)`.  Related: [net/http: add Transport.Clone](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26013)